# Trigger Polymer data-binding change programmatically?

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component

I'm using Polymer's data-bindings to display structured data. Upon clicking a button I want to alter a data-item but the displayed `{{item.name}}` doesn't change.

What am I doing wrong in the following example?

*I simplified as much as possible!*

```
<template id="bind" is="dom-bind">
  <script>
    bind.changeName = function() {
      var repeater = document.querySelector('#repeater');
      repeater.items[0].name = 'New Name' //doesn't work
      repeater.set('items#0.name', 'Another New Name'); // doesn't work as well

    }
  </script>
  <paper-button on-click="changeName">Change name</paper-button>

  <template id="repeater" is="dom-repeat" items='[{"name": "Foo", {"name": "Bar"}]'>
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  </template>
</template>
```

Comment: repeater.set('items.0.name', 'Another New Name'); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'items.0.name'` instead of `'items#0.name'` in the `repeater.set()`, and there is `{` mismatch in the predefined `items` array of `#repeater`. Here is a working demo.

```html
<html>  
<head>

  <title>Template me</title>
  
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/master/webcomponents.js"></script>
  
  <base href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.0.1/lib/">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">  
  <link rel="import" href="paper-button/paper-button.html">  

  
</head>
<body class="fullbleed">

<template id="bind" is="dom-bind">
  <script>
    bind.changeName = function() {
      var repeater = document.querySelector('#repeater');
      //repeater.items[0].name = 'New Name' //doesn't work
      repeater.set('items.0.name', 'Another New Name'); //<==== Now it works ===

    }
  </script>
  <paper-button on-click="changeName">Change name</paper-button>

  <template id="repeater" is="dom-repeat" items='[{"name": "Foo"}, {"name": "Bar"}]'>
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  </template>
</template>


</body>
</html>
```